# try with resources only prints once

Tags: java, try-catch, try-with-resources

I have 5 records in `pList` in the ArrayList below but why does it only print the last record to file ?

I put the `try` first and the `for` loop inside it and that worked but trying to understand the logic why doesn't the code below work ?

```
for(Person p: pList){
    try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("persons.txt")))){
        pw.println(p.toString());
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: It writes all records to a file. However, this code creates a new file on each iteration, so it overwrites the previous iteration's file.

Comment: wow.. can't believe I missed that, yeah that is obviously it